# How to add another variable value to a variable name in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    const healthItemStyle={
        backgroundColor:'green'
    };

    const warningItemStyle={
        backgroundColor:'yellow'
    };

    const errorItemStyle={
        backgroundColor:'red'
    };

    const scenario  = ['AppPulse Active','AppPulse Mobile','AppPulse Trace','BSM-Login','Service Portal'];
    const scenarioHealth  = ['health','warning','health','health','error'];

    const items=scenario.map((item,index)=>{
        return(
            <ListItem style={`${scenarioHealth[index]}ItemStyle`}>
                <ListItemText primary={item} secondary={scenarioHealth[index]}/>
            </ListItem>
        )
    });
```

As shown in the code above， I want to be able to dynamically generate the variable name of the  tag style attribute.
I have tried a lot, like  `${scenarioHealth[index]}ItemStyle`
 but obviously this doesn't work. So ask you any good way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap them with bracket notation to use [computed property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and have all of the `*ItemSyle` in object:

```
const allStyles = {
  healthItemStyle: {...},
  ...
}

<ListItem style={allStyles[`${scenarioHealth[index]}ItemStyle`]}>
```

Here's just an [example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/k0xrknwvw5).

Comment: interesting - didn't know this was possible :)

Comment: can you explain what's happening here a bit more please? thanks!

Comment: @1252748 did you check the link attached in the post?

Comment: yes. i'm aware of computed property names within objects, but it's like something else is happening here. maybe i am just too sleepy to latch on to it properly sorry.

Comment: If you still din't get it then do: `window['healthItemStyle']`. So, it's just a property. Hope, this clears up things.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar  glad to have you answer, but it's does not work for me, this is my git repo https://github.com/NeverMore93/monitor-demo0.git

Comment: @TJSeason, also, in the git I saw using `+ItemStyle`, the `+` is  unnecessary.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar thanks so much, but I still can't run normally in my env. have you tried it yourself?

Comment: @TJSeason, I could have done using `this`  but to make it easier I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could collect you style options together into a single object, and then dynamically select those when rendering your `<ListItem/>` components like so:

```
const allStyles = {
  healthItemStyle : {
      backgroundColor:'green'
  },
  warningItemStyle : {
      backgroundColor:'yellow'
  }, 
  errorItemStyle : {
      backgroundColor:'red'
  }
};

const scenario  = [
  'AppPulse Active','AppPulse Mobile','AppPulse Trace','BSM-Login','Service Portal'
];
const scenarioHealth  = [
  'health','warning','health','health','error'
];

const items=scenario.map((item,index)=>{

    const styleKey = `${ item }ItemStyle`;
    const style = allStyles[ styleKey ];

    return(
        <ListItem style={ style }>
            <ListItemText primary={item} secondary={scenarioHealth[index]}/>
        </ListItem>
    )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close.

Remember that the `style` property of a React component wants to be an object.

What you're doing here:

```
style={`${scenarioHealth[index]}ItemStyle`}>
```

is just setting it to be a string.

Instead, lookup a map of objects like so:

```
    const styles = {
      health: {
        backgroundColor:'green'
      },

      warning: {
         backgroundColor: 'yellow'
      }, 

      error: {
        backgroundColor: 'red'
      }
    }

    const scenario  = ['AppPulse Active','AppPulse Mobile','AppPulse Trace','BSM-Login','Service Portal'];
    const scenarioHealth  = ['health','warning','health','health','error'];

    const items=scenario.map((item,index)=>{
        return(
            <ListItem style={styles[scenarioHealth[index]]}>
                <ListItemText primary={item} secondary={scenarioHealth[index]}/>
            </ListItem>
        )
    });
```

Btw - you might want to take a look at [react-jss](https://github.com/cssinjs/react-jss) which looks a lot like what you're doing here.

Answer (score 0):

`${scenarioHealth[index]}ItemStyle` gives you the correct string, but you need to access the value your variables are holding.

You can change the way your variables are defined. E.g. define one object named `bgColors` and map item to its color:

```
const bgColors = {
    healthItemStyle: 'green',
    warningItemStyle: 'yellow',
    errorItemStyle: 'red'
}
```

Then you can access the color like this:

```
bgColors[`${scenarioHealth[index]}ItemStyle`]
```